# Is the $S_4\times G$ solvable group?

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

We have the following claim : **The group $G$ is solvable iff $S_4\times G$ is solvable.**
If we consider that $S_4\times G$ is solvable we have that $1\times G\leq S_4\times G$ is solvable as a subgroup of solvable group.We consider the isomorphism
$$f:\ 1\times G \to G ,\ (1,g)\mapsto g\ ,$$
so we conclude that G is solvable. From the other hand if we consider that G is solvable we khow that exists a sequense :
$$1=G_m \vartriangleleft G_{m-1} \vartriangleleft \cdots \vartriangleleft G_0=G$$
and $G_{n-1}/G_{n}$ is abelian group, $\forall n\in \{1,\cdots, m\}$.Also we khow that $S_4$ is solvable with the following sequence
$$1\vartriangleleft H \vartriangleleft A_4 \vartriangleleft S_4$$
with $H=\{1,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$.How can we show that $S_4\times G$ is solvable group?

Comment: Hint: Take the direct product with $G$ with each of the members of the sequence for $S_4$.

Comment: More generally, the direct product of finitely many groups is solvable if and only if each factor is solvable. This is not true for infinitely many solvable groups if their derived lengths are unbounded.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct product of any two solvable groups is solvable. More generally any extension of a solvable group by a solvable group is solvable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I suppose in this case the sequense : $$ 1\times G \leq H\times G \leq A_4\times G \leq S_4 \times G$$ has the properties we want.

Comment: You have to add to it the derived sequence of $G$.